# Spring issue - must have even number of URI's

Tags: java, spring, drools

I am getting the following error when I start my tomcat server.

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 151; SchemaLocation: schemaLocation value = 
'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
 http://drools.org/schema/drools-spring 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd' must have even number of URI's.
```

but my xml has different

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:drools="http://drools.org/schema/drools-spring"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation=
       "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://drools.org/schema/drools-spring
   http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/labs/labs/jbossrules/trunk/drools-container/drools-spring/src/main/resources/org/drools/container/spring/drools-spring-1.0.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">
```

which has drools-spring-1.0.0.xsd reference. I am not sure why this is not shown in the error message. Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that the file you call "my xml" is the one that is actually processed by the SAX parser?

Comment: It sounds like the Tomcat application has an old version of the xml file missing the drool xsd. If you are deploying a war file, unpack it and check the content of the xml file. If you are running it from an IDE, rebuild the artefact and check that the xml file was copied into the runtime class path. Followup question, why are you still defining spring contexts in xml files ?

Comment: not sure how to accept Klaus reply as an answer. Thanks Klaus

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Klaus Groenbaek and laune for the clue. When I extracted the jar, I have seen the file present in target folder doesnt have the entry, I maven cleaned and installed the project and also modified the order of the schemas as suggested in some other forums. Issue is fixed now.